# Roman to Decimal Number conversion

Tags: number-systems

I am trying to convert **CIIXMXCVCII** to decimal number. However, I am not getting it completely if it's a valid roman number representation or not.
I tried this online tool: http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/roman_decimal/ which says it's equivalent to 1277. However, roman representation of 1277 should be **MCCLXXVII** in my opinion. 
Can somebody clarify my doubt?
Are both of these roman representation pointing to the same decimal number?

Thanks!

PS: Motivation for this comes from this mathematical joke:
[image]

Comment: oh my god. I have no idea. Sorry.

Comment: Should be PG for _pergrandis_. :)

Answer (score 1):

The subtractive rule became “standard” only during the Middle Ages. But it's limited in application: only I, X and C can be used for subtraction (once) and next to a symbol of the “next size”:

- I can be used before V or X
- X can be used before L or C
- C can be used before D or M

(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)

Thus $1999$ can be represented as MCMXCIX, not as MIM. The notation is in order from the highest units to the lowest:

> M CM XC IX

that would be, without the abbrevations,

> M D CCCC L XXXX V IIII

In Latin, the number would be spelled *mille nongenti nonaginta novem* and the number system reflected the names. So IM would mean nothing: Romans were not really good with arithmetic. `;)` This can be found in modern usage, however.

I can't see any sensible way to parse CIIXMXCVCII. The tool you mention converts MIIM into $2000$ and IMIIM into $1999$, so I'm under the impression that it discards “illegal” subtractive symbols; if we remove II (as CIIX is converted to $110$) we get CXMXCVCII: $100+990+90+5+100+2=1287$ so I don't see where $1277$ comes from. Another example is VVCVCIV that's converted to $199$, while removing the first C gives VVVCIV that's converted to $109$.

Comment: 100+990+90+95+2 = 1277 [ C, XM, XC, VC, II ]

Comment: @BitBlitz XM is not a legal numeral

Comment: I'm just explaining how the code that computed 1277 may have come up with that answer.

Comment: "the number system reflected the names".  Q: how does nongenti (900) correspond to a preference between the numerals DCCCC & CM?

Comment: @BitBlitz The subtractive notation became largely used only in the middle ages, and there was no “preference”, actually: a Roman would have used DCCCC.

Comment: interesting, thanks.  One more question: If the Romans didn't originate subtractive notation, then who did, and who decided/decides whether XM is or is not legal? It seems perhaps there is no "official" guide for correctness...?

Comment: @BitBlitz The Romans *did* use the subtractive notation, but not in a systematic way: this is reflected in the names of 18 and 19, respectively *duodeviginti* and *undeviginti*. Inscriptions have been found where 18 was written IIXX, quite likely to save space. Sometimes IV for IIII was used.

Answer (score 0):

You can sensibly parse it by recursively applying a hypothetical rule "any pending smaller number is subtracted from a larger subsequent number" by using a stack.  (WikiPedia does say double subtractives are known...)

```
C = 100 (push 100)
II = 2 (push 2)
X = 8 (10 - pop 2 = push 8)
M (1000 - 108) (pop 100 & 8, push 1000 - 108 = 892) 
X = push 10
C = 90  (pop 10, push 90)
V = push 5
C = 95  (pop 5, push 95)
II = 2 push 2

At end, pop and add all numbers = 2 + 95 + 90 + 892 = 1079

E.g. IVX = 10 - 4 = 6.
```

Not saying my method is officially sanctioned in any way  - but it is a possible interpretation and will yield a number in any case.